# Convert Java Comparator to Scala Ordering

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I'm looking for a simple and elegant way to convert Java `Comparator` to scala `Ordering`.

**Use case:**

I have a Scala collection that I want to sort using a comparator defined in Java code:

```
val comparator = getComparator()
val collection = Seq("a","b")
collection.sorted(???)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already an implicit conversion in the standard library: [`scala.math.Ordering.comparatorToOrdering`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/math/Ordering$.html#comparatorToOrdering[A](implicitcmp:java.util.Comparator[A]):scala.math.Ordering[A])

You just need an import to use it:

```scala
import scala.math.Ordering.comparatorToOrdering

val comparator = getComparator()
val collection = Seq("a","b")
collection.sorted(comparator)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, the  [Ordering](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/math/Ordering.html) companion contains an implicit conversion from Comparable[A] to Ordering[A]:

> You can import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits to gain access to other implicit orderings.

Example:

```
import java.util.Date

val dateOrdering = implicitly[Ordering[Date]]
import dateOrdering._

val now = new Date
val later = new Date(now.getTime + 1000L)

now < later ... should be true
```

Comment: What is more important there is also implicit `Ordering.comparatorToOrdering` method so you don't need to make one yourself as @Harper does, just import it. See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/math/Ordering$.html#comparatorToOrdering[A](implicitcmp:java.util.Comparator[A]):scala.math.Ordering[A]

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found so far is to define your own implicit conversion between java.util.Comparator and Ordering

```
implicit def comparatorToOrdering[T](comparator: Comparator[T]) = 
new Ordering[T] {
     def compare(x: T, y: T): Int = comparator.compare(x, y)
}
```

Import this and then you can write

```
val comparator = getComparator()
val collection = Seq("a","b")
collection.sorted(comparator)
```